# How do I access the model and Metadata within a custom ActionFilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, metadata, viewdata

```
public class CheckMetadataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // get model
        // get metadata for each model property
        // set viewdata if metadata X exists
    }
}
```

Old question was: How do I access ViewData within a custom ModelMetadataProvider? That was a no go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't/should not access ViewData or any HttpContext related info in a model metadata provider.

---

UPDATE:

After the updated question things start to make a little sense, so let's update the answer:

```
public class CheckMetadataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        // get model?
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        if (result != null)
        {
            var model = result.Model;
            if (model != null)
            {
                // get metadata for model (you have a single model, no idea what you meant by "for each model" in your question)
                var metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, model.GetType());
                if (metadata.DisplayName == "foo bar")
                {
                    // set viewdata if metadata X exists
                    filterContext.Controller.ViewData["foo"] = "bar";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This being said, obviously, using `ViewData` in an ASP.NET MVC application is something that I  absolutely recommend against. `ViewData` is weakly typed. Whatever you are trying to achieve (would have been nice by the way if you have explained what is your goal), don't use ViewData, use view models and strongly typed views.

Personally I am allergic to things like ViewBag/ViewData in ASP.NET MVC applications. When I do code reviews and see people using them I know they did something wrong.

Comment: I am aware that this may not be the best place. I would still like to know if it is possible to access ViewData.

Comment: @Jared, a model metadata provider is absolutely not the right place to access something such as ViewData whose lifecycle is much different than the one of the metadata provider. There are other ways to achieve whatever you are trying to achieve. And to answer your question, no, this is not possible, there is no connection between those two systems and there shouldn't be because they accomplish two entirely different purposes that shouldn't be mixed.

Comment: OK, looks like that is a no go. How about accessing metadata from a custom action filter? (question and code changed)

Comment: By for each model, I meant each property on the model. What I am trying to do is simple. I have properties on a model that have changed from text to dropdowns. Making it a dropdown was easy and it picks up its items from a viewdata item of the same name. What I am trying to do is inspect the metadata, and if a property has a UIHint of "DropDownList" then resolve a class with the name "{Property}SelectListBuilder" and stuff that into ViewData. In other words, I am trying to create a convention for "DropDownList" properties that automatically get values from a datasource class.